# Web Application To Move Data from Microsoft SQL Server to Clouer Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, web, hdfs, sqoop

I am developing a web application to move data from Microsoft SQL Server data to Cloudera Hadoop. Please give Some Suggestions.

Comment: .... what have you tried, what error are you encountering precisely? SO isn't a code-writing factory.... you need to work on your end a bit more

Answer (score 2):

So [Sqoop2](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/index.html) is being actively developed for this exact purpose. Also, the [Hue](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorials-series-ii-8-how-to-transfer-data/) project has a Sqoop2 app, which uses Sqoop to batch transfer data.